# Invalid ssh key entry - unrecognized format: ssh-rsa AAAA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

`{ insertId: "1uvaqlxfcfvjgw" jsonPayload: { localTimestamp: "2023-01-30T11:32:57.2877Z" message: "Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: selman_keskin:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...= google-ssh {"userName":"selman.keskin@company.com","expireOn":"2023-01-30T11:32:49+0000"}" omitempty: null } labels: {1} logName: "projects/xxx-testproject/logs/GCEGuestAgent" receiveTimestamp: "2023-01-30T11:32:57.610158055Z" resource: {2} severity: "ERROR" sourceLocation: {3} timestamp: "2023-01-30T11:32:57.287845863Z" }`

On GCP stream logs, get this error.
Are there any bug on non_windows_accounts.go?

troubleshooting ssh errors
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors

resolve the "Invalid ssh key entry - unrecognized format: ssh-rsa AAAA..." error